# Fortran - two-branch IF statement from old (1972) code

Tags: fortran

Greetings.  Does anyone know what this Fortran IF statement is doing?

```
IF(IJJ-2) ,409,411
```

I don't think it's a typo because there are a few other in the same program.  I assumed it was a standard arithmetic IF that simply defaulted the "less than 0" branch to the next exectutbale statement, but I'm not sure about that.  I think this code was hosted on a CDC 6600 around 1970-1972.  I looked through the FORTRAN 77 subset standard but it specifies all three statement lables must be supplied. Any advice is most appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It's called an arithmetic IF statement and is obsolete in Fortran 90 and 95. However, I know the Intel Fortran Compiler still supports it. If the expression within the parentheses is less than zero then execution transfers to the first label. If equal to zero then the second label, and finally if greater than zero it transfers to the third label. I'm not sure what happens in the case of a missing label - I'm assuming it just falls through.

So your IF statement would translate into modern Fortran as:

```
IF (IJJ == 2) THEN
    GOTO 409
ELSEIF (IJJ > 2) THEN
    GOTO 411
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the destination line numbers were for less than, equal to, and greater than zero.
This doesn't look like standard fortran, but at a guess the missing line numbers will
drop through to the next statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely non-standard Fortran. I checked and both the Intel and GFortran compilers will not accept it. Many Fortran compilers back before F90 had non-standard extensions. I remember that the DEC compiler had many extensions. And this was used a selling point! It also helped ensure customer loyalty since code that used these extensions could not be ported to another compilers. Your best bet is if you can find the manual that came with the compiler it should document this. Good Luck!

As an historical side note, I remember being told that some of the companies back then were so jealous of their turf, and the advantage that their non-standard extensions gave them, that they purposely hindered the standards process to delay the next version of Fortran (which was eventually called F90). This allowed other languages to gain dominance and hastened the downfall of Fortran.

Comment: By extension you mean this type of if statement, or the missing first label? Because Arithmetic IF is still part of Fortran 2008.

Comment: This answer reefers to the missing first label which is nonstandard. The Arithmetic IF is standard but is currently an obsolescent construct.